# negative numbers in Binary Tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

I want to multiply each node with negative value -2 in Binary Tree. But I do not know how to implement it. When multiplying with negative number left and right sub trees change their place. I got stuck at doing this.

```
 typedef struct BTree {
    int value;
    struct BTree *left, *right;
} BTree;

BTree *insert(BTree *root, int value) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        BTree *new_node = (BTree*) malloc(sizeof(BTree));
        new_node->value = value;
        new_node->left = new_node->right = NULL;
        return new_node;
    }
    if (value < root->value) {        
        root->left = insert(root->left, value);
    }
    else if (value > root->value) {   
        root->right = insert(root->right, value);
    }
    else {

    }
    return root;
}

void print_tree(BTree *root)
{
    if (root == NULL) return;
    print_tree(root->left);
    printf("%d ", root->value);
    print_tree(root->right);
}



   void swap_tree(BTree *root)  
{ 
  if (root == NULL)  
    return;   
  else 
  { 
    BTree *temp; 

    swap_tree(root->left); 
    swap_tree(root->right); 

    temp        = root->left; 
    root->left  = root->right; 
    root->right = temp; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: You want to multiply a node? You mean, your nodes contain values and you want to multiply those values? Please edit your question and include your code so we can have a better look.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `(BTree*) malloc(sizeof(BTree));` typecast is needless.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you are talking about binary search tree and not just a binary tree. As you correctly noted multiplying all the values in the nodes of a binary search tree will lead to changing the order of the subtrees at each node. How you implement that will depend on the tree representation that you are using, but for most a recursion based approach that swaps the two child nodes at each node starting from the leafs should work.

Comment: There is no need for recursion. If the tree includes limks to parents, then a traversal is simple without recursion. If it does not, a traversal only requires an array of pointers to nodes in the current path from the root, with as many elements as the tree depth.

Comment: @EricPostpischil having a look at the structure that OP now included in the question I still believe recursion is the most natural approach

Comment: “Natural”? We should use more resources than necessary because it is “natural”? Do you mean “easy” or “low effort”? What is gained by using a “natural” approach?

Comment: @EricPostpischil feel free to add another answer with the approach you propose, I don't believe these comments will lead to any constructive discussion that will lead to improving the quality of my answer

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I did the swapping of nodes in tree. One more thing is left to multiply each node value with -2.

Comment: @EmilBədrəddinli this should be pretty straight forward - simply multiple the node's value by `-2`.

Comment: @EmilBədrəddinli You could do the multiplication in the same function as `swap_tree`, but rename it. Perhaps have a general `multiply_tree_by_constant` recursive function that multiplies each node by a (non-zero) constant and swaps the pointers if the constant is negative.

Comment: @IanAbbott I could not do within the swap function

Comment: You don't have to do that in the swap function, do the multiplication and the swap as two separate steps in the recursive function